# How to install Greenplum Database in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, greenplum, bigdata

I have tried installing it from my side but have failed. I had referred to the tutorial that was given by the link http://nixustechnologies.com/2014/03/install-greenplum-community-edition/ . I had tried installing it but the error that pops out is

```
could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Please either help me getting it resolved or If you have any other alternative for installing Greenplum Database in Ubuntu 14.04 that please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at this https://greenplum.org/install-greenplum-oss-on-ubuntu/ to get detailed instructions on how to install greenplum on ubuntu now. However, note that they use a higher version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Greenplum Database doesn't support Ubantu, 
It is only supported by

1.SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2

2.CentOS 5.0 or higher

3.Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5.0 or higher

4.Oracle Unbreakable Linux 5.5

Answer (score 0):

That link describes installing Greenplum on CentOS/RHEL.  Greenplum doesn't have a build for Ubuntu.  You could probably build from the source code to get it to work on Ubuntu or you could upgrade your operating system.